# Editing Photoshop layers in Sketch

Tags: adobe-photoshop, sketch-app

Can I edit Photoshop layers from a PSD file in Sketch?

If not, is there a way to import a PSD into Sketch?

Answer (score 1):

PSD layer editing is not possible in Sketch for the moment. Nevertheless, you can import your PSD in Sketch with **insert > image**.